# Visual Studio Code. Convert "///" comments to summary comments

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

It used to be that VSCode would identify and show the description for methods, classes etc that had a simple "///" kind of comment in C#. However, recently these comment descriptions are no longer shown in intelisense.

Thus, I thought of doing a Regex Search & Replace which will convert all "///" comment lines to summary comment lines.
So basically turning something like this:

```
///this is a comment
public class MyClass { }
```

Into this:

```
///<summary>this is a comment</summary>
public class MyClass { }
```

My regex sucks though :)
Anyone can help?
Thank you.

Comment: `///` is not anything special in regex, so you can just input that verbatim

Comment: Do the 3 "/" characters have to appear anyplace special, like the start of a line?  Otherwise, regexReplace(MyText,"([^/]///)([^\r\n]*)", "$1<summary>$2</summary>").

Comment: "///" can be anywhere. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the find widget or the Search across files with these settings:

```
"find": "///(?!<summary>)(.*)",
"replace": "///<summary>$1</summary>",
"isRegex": true,
```

If this is something you do frequently you may want to save a keybinding or command to do this using an extension I wrote: [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform).  Here is what a find in the current file keybinding would look like:

```
{
    "key": "alt+r",
    "command": "findInCurrentFile",
    "args": {
        "find": "///(?!<summary>)(.*)",
        "replace": "///<summary>$1</summary>",
        "isRegex": true,
        // "matchWholeWord": true,
        // "matchCase": true,

        "restrictFind": "nextSelect",  // to do them one by one
        // eliminate this arg if you just want to do them all at once
    }
},
```

This keybinding would do a search across whatever files you want using the Search Panel:

```
{
    "key": "alt+z",
    "command": "runInSearchPanel",
    "args": {
        "find": "///(?!<summary>)(.*)",
        "replace": "///<summary>$1</summary>",
        "isRegex": true,
        // "filesToInclude": "${relativeFile}", // to restrict to the current file
        // "filesToExclude": "",
        "triggerSearch": true,
    }
}
```

Here is a demo of both methods:

[image: transform comment with extension]